# Confused about When to Use “these” and “those”

Tags: grammar, difference, pronouns, demonstrative

Example #1

> This site contains links to books that I read. I recommend
>   **these/those** books.

*NOTE: The links are on this site, but not on this page. The links are **external links**.*

Should I use **these** or **those**? Why?

---

Example #2

> This page contains links to books that I read. I recommend
>   **these/those** books.

*NOTE: The links are on this page, but you might have to scroll down a little to find them. The links are **external links**.*

Should I use **these** or **those**? Why?

---

Example #3

> I read “Book Name + Link”, “Book Name + Link”, and “Book Name + Link”.
>   I recommend **these/those** books.

*NOTE: The links are **external links**.*

Should I use **these** or **those**? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. “Those”**

I liken this use to someone *talking* about books, and pointing to a stack of books they've read. I imagine someone pointing to that stack and saying, "I recommend those books." If he were holding them in his hand, he'd say "these."

**2. “These”**

The links are, in the spirit of the previous example, "in hand."

**3. “These”**

Again, these links are "in hand" even if the links are to an external site.

Comment: A deli in my hometown sold three kinds of donuts – plain, sugar, and cinnamon – but the butcher who owned the place used three labels: THEM, THESE, and THOSE, and would insist customers use those terms when ordering. A newcomer asking for one plain donut and two cinnamon donuts would be told: "Look, we've got three kinds of donuts – them, these, and those – so wadd'ya want?" The customer would then say, "Oh, give me two of those and one of them." It's a bit odd how, no matter what a customer wants, it can be said in any order, and the sentence never sounds off.