# For these reasons vs for those reasons

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "these" or "those" to refer to previously mentioned arguments? I can give some context:

Paragraph 2: Argument A

Paragraph 3: Argument B

Paragraph 4: Argument C

Paragraph 5: For th_se reasons I would like to apply to this scholarship, since.......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between These & Those.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52477/difference-between-these-those) Also [“These” or “Those” in an essay?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166860/these-or-those-in-an-essay), [Confused about When to Use “these” and “those”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17873/confused-about-when-to-use-these-and-those), and many others.

Comment: Note that there's something a bit "awkward" about your example context, because both ***for these/those reasons*** and ***since*** actually mean ***because***, so you're essentially saying ***Because** [reason1], [statement], **because** [reason2]*. Which would usually be expressed as ***Because** [reason1] **and** [reason2], [statement]*.

Comment: Usually we apply *to* an institution, and *for* a position, an award, or a scholarship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you probably should us "these", but both are acceptable.

- **For these reasons** must be *near* to the reasons
- **For those reasons** must be *after* the reasons.

Good:

- "I'm poor.  I'm sick.  For these reasons, I'm not going to the party."
- "I'm not going to the party for these reasons: I'm poor and I'm sick."
- "Chapter 1 explained the history.  Chapter 2 explained the current situation.  Chapter 3 explained the consequences.  For those reasons, we can't accept this policy change."
- "Chapter 1 explained the history.  Chapter 2 explained the current situation.  Chapter 3 explained the consequences.  For these reasons, we can't accept this policy change."

Bad:

- <strike>"I'm not going to the party for those reasons: I'm poor and I'm sick."</strike>