# All examples using "since"

Tags: since

After read a [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/234669/104001) about the use of "these" I've been noticed that a britanic person explains that "since" must be mean "because" in that context. I'm surprised about a simple alternative use of a word where I didn't get why the real meaning is a explanation and not a condition.

The example:

> Paragraph 2: Argument A
>
> Paragraph 3: Argument B
>
> Paragraph 4: Argument C
>
> Paragraph 5: For th_se reasons I would like to apply to this scholarship, since.......

Then the person explained:

> Note that there's something a bit "awkward" about your example context, because both ***for these/those reasons*** and ***since*** actually mean ***because***, so you're essentially saying ***Because*** [reason1], [statement], **because** [reason2]. Which would usually be expressed as ***Because*** [reason1] **and** [reason2], [statement].

Please,let me know what are the ***most common*** use of "since" for native speakers.

Comment: Answering this kind of question is why we have dictionaries.

Comment: @ThePhoton but I think it do not must be means "because" since "since" is a conditional conjunction too.

Comment: I don't get your point. Are you saying they can't mean the same thing if they're the same part of speech?

Comment: @ThePhoton no, I'm suppose they can mean the same but not must mean the same thing. To complete the phrase I would suggest a condition instead of a explanation. "because" is relative to "I would like to apply to this scholarship".On the other hand, "since" is relative to "these reasons".

Comment: Instead an explanation I mean. Sorry.

Comment: You need to review the use of since in a grammar book.

Answer (score 1):

*Since* can have the same meaning as *because* in certain circumstances, but not in all cases.

When we want to connect two clauses describing a result and its cause, we can use either *because* or *since*.

> [Since/Because] I live in California, I can take vacations at the beach or in the mountains.

But when we want to introduce a noun or noun phrase representing a cause, we can only use *because* (with *of*):

> My trip cost more than I expected, *because of* [not *since*] the high price of gas.

---

In your question, it's not clear if the phrases you introduced with *since* are noun phrases or clauses, so we don't know whether your usage was standard or not.

You also asked,

> Please,let me know what are the most common use of "since" for native speakers.

This question can be answered by referring to a dictionary.

Comment: My mistake was comparing the english grammar with my native language. Sometimes it works but I just noticed now that it isn't a good idea. I remember that I read some texts where the meaning of conjunction "since" is a condition so that I need native speakers explanation about that use.

Comment: I didn't know about the use of "since/because" in verbal and nominal phrases. Thank you for teaching me the grammar! Now every time I use that words I'll pay attention to not get wrong. Do native speakers notice the difference in spoken english?

Comment: @J-Mello, yes it would sound incorrect to a native speaker if you said, for example, "I am going to be late since the slow traffic" instead of "I am going to be late since the traffic is slow".

Comment: In fact! That is the reason why I'm studying collocations. I have installed 3 collocation dictionaries in my phone. Every day I learn something. Even before typing here sometimes I Google it to be certain that I'm correct.